# Clear dynamic range vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear a dynamic range starting on cell M22 using and going to last column but the use of last column is eluding me.

Thanks

```
Sub clear()
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\..\Master Info Page.xlsx"


  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastCol = .Cells(13, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row
  End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(M22, 13), Cells(Lastrow, lastCol)).Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just do:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("M22", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Clear
End With
```

Comment: Just to note that we can use just `Rows.Count` and `Columns.Count` but it makes absolutely no difference :)

Comment: In the majority of cases, that is true.  Without the sheet qualifier, Rows.Count and Columns.Count returns the number of rows and columns that the application can support, so if opened in Excel 2007 it will be a number much higher than a .xls workbook which could result in an error (cell M1048576 doesn't exist in a .xls file).  So with the poster opening a file, it is possible that they will want to use the Sheet's row and column counts instead of the application's.  However, the poster is opening a .xlsx file, so it's likely that this small point of mine is moot :P

Comment: thanks this worked great. Also Thanks Andy G `Range("M22").CurrentRegion.Clear` worked great as well.